# NControlView not rendering the controls of library in UWP

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp, ngraphics

The controls are not rendering in my project. I have read that for IOS and android I need to initialize library by "NControls.Init()" or "NControlVireRenderer.Init()" but in UWP both init methods are unavailable.

Does this library support UWP apps or not. If Yes, can anyone let me know the way to use it in UWP.
Thanks in advance.

I have tried installing NControl.NetCore and NControl.Controls both nuget in my Xamarin.Forms project in both .NetStandard and UWP.

Version Info-

.NetStandard 2.0
Xamarin.Forms 3.6
Visual Studio 2017

Comment: The highest Store app's version supported by `NControls` is 8.1. It no longer applies to UWP.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Thanks for the quick response. 
Ques 1. Is there any other library which can be used for custom controls.
Ques 2. As I am migrating my app from 8.1 to UWP and have lots of controls made with the help of NControl library. Do I have to write from scratch all them again in native.